# How to Implement a Queue With Two Stacks

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue

Today I had a data structures exam. One of the questions was how to implement queue functions which are enqueue and dequeue given stacks `s1` and `s2`. I have used this method, is this correct?

```
enqueue(& item)
   if(!s2.isEmpty())
      s1.push(s2.pop());
   s1.push(item);
dequeue
   if(!s1.isEmpty())
      s2.push(s1.pop());
   return s2.pop();
```

Comment: @kirk And now you know to proof read three times anything that comes out of SwiftKey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically if you have a stack like this:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

The problem here is that popping will want to pop in a LIFO order, meaning it would want to pop element `4`. A queue should pop in FIFO order and pop element `1`.

To get this kind of behavior, we basically need to be able to pop in reverse order. A second stack can allow us to actually reverse the contents of a stack. Imagine looping through the stack above and popping from it and pushing the contents to another stack:

```
[1,2,3,4] []
[1,2,3]   [4]
[1,2]     [4,3]
[1]       [4,3,2]
[]        [4,3,2,1]
```

Now when we pop from the second stack, we pop 1 as desired.

But to do this in proper order, we have to first loop through *all* the elements of the first stack and transfer them to the second. So there should actually be loops in your enqueue/dequeue operation to flip (reverse) the contents of these stacks.

That's where the second stack comes in handy: it lets you reverse the contents of a stack through a transfer. But you're going to need a loop for that, since imagine enqueuing 4 elements. Now to dequeue, you need a loop to reverse the contents. You could treat `s1` as the pushing stack and `s2` as the popping stack. It seems you had the right idea but we need a slight tweak:

```
enqueue(item):
   while(!s2.isEmpty())
      s1.push(s2.pop());
   s1.push(item);

dequeue(item):
   while(!s1.isEmpty())
      s2.push(s1.pop());
   return s2.pop();
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, the enqueue doesn't need a loop.  If you have two stacks, enqueueStack and dequeueStack, you just need to push onto enqueueStack and reverse onto dequeueStack whenever it's empty.

```
enqueue(item):
    enqueueStack.push(item);
dequeue(item):
    if(dequeueStack.isEmpty()){
        while(!enqueueStack.isEmpty()){
            dequeueStack.push(enqueueStack.pop());
        }
    }
    return dequeueStack.pop()
```

Saves a little time if the stacks get large.